# How to change the function that it can transform more than one date to julian days

Tags: r, function, days, julian-date

The Following function, orginal from [R - convert POSIXct to fraction of julian day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594235/r-convert-posixct-to-fraction-of-julian-day/38318219#38318219) is the function I would like to change.

```
julian_conv <- function(x) { 
if (is.na(x)) { 
  return(NA)
}
else {
j <-julian(x, origin = as.POSIXlt(paste0(format(x, "%Y"),'-01-01')))
temp <- unclass(j) 
return(temp[1] + 1) 
}
}
```

The function turns a date into julian days.
Example:

```
date <- as.POSIXct('2006-12-12 12:00:00')
julian_conv(date)
#[1] 345.5
```

Is it possible to change the function that it can change more than one date at the time? For example the following dates:

```
date <- as.POSIXct(c('2006-12-12 13:00:00', '2013-12-12 12:00:00', '2020-12-12 12:00:00'))
```

Comment: To make sure solutions generalize well, I'd suggest modifying your sample data to have dates in different years - including some in leap years.

Comment: The simplest would be to use `sapply(date, julian_conv)`.